# SLIME and SWANK Fail on a MIPS Architecture

Tags: emacs, common-lisp, mips, slime, swank

I am trying to use Emacs with [SLIME](https://common-lisp.net/project/slime/) and Swank on an [Imagination Creator CI20](http://blog.imgtec.com/powervr/mips-creator-ci20-development-board-now-available) Mips board to learn Common Lisp. I am using SBCL and Clisp as my compiler/interpreter (mainly SBCL which is usually set as the inferior-lisp-mode); I did however test this with both SBCL and Clisp set as the inferior-lisp-mode and it fails with both. I tried to run SLIME but it invariably fails while trying to load or compile a Swank file. The error message from one of the attempts suggests that it is having difficulty with the architecture (Mips - little endian). I am running the default install of Debian 7 Wheezy (Mipsel) the board comes with.

I tried this with [SLIME](https://common-lisp.net/project/slime/) installed via apt-get from the Debian repository, another time with the Melpa install of SLIME and lastly another attempt with the Github git repository (latest) of SLIME. They all fail though the error messages are sometimes subtly different. It fails with both Emacs 23 and 24.

I am attaching the error messages/blurb from my attempt with the Github repository of SLIME, using SBCL as the compiler. SBCL was installed from the SBCL repository since Mipsel Wheezy seems not to have it in the Debian repository. It does seem to be a somewhat older version but is the latest binary for the Mips architecture on the [SBCL website](http://www.sbcl.org/platform-table.html). SBCL runs fine as a REPL from the command line.

```
(progn (load "/usr/share/common-lisp/source/slime/swank-loader.lisp" :verbose t) (funcall (read-from-string "swank-loader:init")) (funcall (read-from-string "swank:start-server") "/tmp/slime.4482"))

This is SBCL 1.0.28, an implementation of ANSI Common Lisp.
More information about SBCL is available at <http://www.sbcl.org/>.

SBCL is free software, provided as is, with absolutely no warranty.
It is mostly in the public domain; some portions are provided under
BSD-style licenses.  See the CREDITS and COPYING files in the
distribution for more information.
* 
; loading #P"/usr/share/common-lisp/source/slime/swank-loader.lisp"
WARNING:
   No architecture feature found in (POWERPC PPC X86 X86-64 X86_64 AMD64 I686
                                     I586 I486 PC386 IAPX386 SPARC64 SPARC
                                     HPPA64 HPPA ARM PENTIUM3 PENTIUM4 JAVA-1.4
                                     JAVA-1.5 JAVA-1.6 JAVA-1.7).

debugger invoked on a SB-C::INPUT-ERROR-IN-COMPILE-FILE:
  READ failure in COMPILE-FILE:
    SB-INT:SIMPLE-READER-PACKAGE-ERROR at 5799 (line 150, column 52) on #<SB-SYS:FD-STREAM for "file /usr/share/common-lisp/source/slime/swank-loader.lisp" {50007F71}>:
      Symbol "APPLY-OUTPUT-TRANSLATIONS" not found in the ASDF package.

Type HELP for debugger help, or (SB-EXT:QUIT) to exit from SBCL.

restarts (invokable by number or by possibly-abbreviated name):
  0: [ABORT] Exit debugger, returning to top level.

(SB-C::READ-FOR-COMPILE-FILE
 #<SB-SYS:FD-STREAM for "file /usr/share/common-lisp/source/slime/swank-loader.lisp" {50007F71}>
 5418)
0]
```

Comment: Looks like it might be trying to cross-compile for MIPS instead of using the native MIPS gcc.

Answer (score 3):

That version of SBCL is too old to work with current SLIME. Try building and installing a new version of SBCL with the sources from http://www.sbcl.org and see if that improves the situation.

Comment: I just grabbed the binary from the SBCL site, since I could not use apt-get to download one from Debian on that architecture. Please note that trying to install and run Slime using Clisp as the interpreter also fails but the infinite error message (essentially a repeat of the same message) was even more cryptic, so I am not sure if it is just an issue with SBCL. I can also try with any other CL compiler or interpreter that SLIME supports but my options seem to be quite limited on Mips. Will try to compile SBCL from source tonight.

Comment: I did attempt to compile, the current version of SBCL (1.28), using either the older vesion of SBCL or Clisp. Both failed to compile SBCL.